# How to run firebase query function properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I have the button in HTML which query the table data, but it only works for the first button which made me frustrated. My purpose is to pass id to the function and Here is my code:

Does anyone have idea? Thank in advance!!!!

```
 <html>
<button id="Tsuen" onclick="tsuenWanQuery(this.id)"      class="myButton2">Tsuen</button>
<button id="Yuen" onclick="tsuenWanQuery(this.id)" class="myButton2">Yuen</button>
<button id="Kwai" class="myButton2" onclick="kwaiChingQuery()">Kwai</button>
<button id="Tuen"   class="myButton2" onclick="tuenMunQuery()">Tuen</button>
</html>



function tsuenWanQuery(id){
console.log("onjjj") 
var Ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");
  Ref.orderByChild('Region').equalTo(id).once('child_added').then(function (snap) {
 var subject = snap.child("subject").val();
 var region = snap.child("region").val();
 var form = snap.child("form").val();
 var code = snap.child("code").val();
 var pay = snap.child("fee").val();
 console.log(snap.child("").val());

 modal.style.display = "none";
 $("#table_body").empty().append("<tr><td>" + form + "</td><td>" +  code + "</td><td>" + region + "</td><td>" + pay);


});


};
```